# OrientDB - show both edge and vertex properties

Tags: orientdb

I have vertex class **host** with property **hostname** and edge class **link** with property **ports** which is a list.

So hosts are connected to each other with link having ports.

I need to find out who is connected to one specific **'myhost'** like:

```
host1.hostname -- link1.ports 
host2.hostname -- link2.ports
etc
```

However, I'm only able to achieve:

```
host1@rid -- ports1 
host2@rid -- ports2
```

with query like:

```
select expand(inE(link).include('ports','out*')) from host where hostname = 'myhost'
```

or I can get hostnames and ports as list, yet not very useful:

```
[host1.hostname, host2.hostname] -- [link1.ports, link2.ports]

select in('link').hostname,inE('link').ports from host where hostname = 'myhost'
```

Unwind in that query doesn't do the thing, too.

Is there any proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the Match statement?

https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Match.html

Try this

```
match { class: host, as : host1, where: (hostname = "myhost") }
.inE('link'){as: link}
.outV(){as: host2}
return host1.hostname,link.ports, host2.hostname
```